# How to add inputs to an empty list and keep it stored?

Tags: python, list, function, append, storage

I am trying to make a list for items in a game and I have to call it multiple times in my program. I noticed that the inputs don't store in my list and it just replaces it every time.

I used `playeritems.append()` and `playeritems.extend()` but it does not work.

```
def addbackpack():
    global playeritems
    gameitems= ["sword", "potion"]
    playeritems = []
    print ("\nWhat would you like to add to your backpack? The sword or potion?\n")
    p1_additem = str(input())
    if p1_additem in gameitems:
        playeritems.append(p1_additem)
        print ("\nYou added",p1_additem,"to your backpack.\n")
    else:
        print ("\nThat is not a choice!\n")
        return addbackpack()

addbackpack()
print (playeritems)
addbackpack()
print (playeritems)
```

This is my exact result after inputting sword first and potion second:

```
What would you like to add to your backpack? The sword or potion?

sword

You added sword to your backpack

['sword']

What would you like to add to your backpack? The sword or potion?

potion

You added potion to your backpack

['potion']
```

Comment: don't use a recursive call, just use a loop in your function, and return the list.

Comment: You are resetting the value of `playeritems` each time you call `addbackpack()`.  You need to pass the current value of `playeritems` to `addbackpack(playeritems)` to keep the current items as well as the new items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def addbackpack(playeritems):
    gameitems= ["sword", "potion"]
    print ("\nWhat would you like to add to your backpack? The sword or potion?\n")
    p1_additem = str(input())
    if p1_additem in gameitems:
        playeritems.append(p1_additem)
        print ("\nYou added",p1_additem,"to your backpack.\n")
    else:
        print ("\nThat is not a choice!\n")
        return addbackpack(playeritems)
playeritems = []
addbackpack(playeritems)
print (playeritems)
addbackpack(playeritems)
print (playeritems)
```

- You were reinitializing playeritems every time you make a function call. Instead just pass a list to function call.

PS : I suggest not to use recursion. Instead you can do this iterative way.

```
def addbackpack():
    gameitems= ["sword", "potion"]
    print ("\nWhat would you like to add to your backpack? The sword or potion?\n")
    p1_additem = str(input())
    # read until player input correct item.
    while p1_additem not in gameitems:
      print ("\nThat is not a choice!\n")
      p1_additem = str(input())
    playeritems.append(p1_additem)
    print ("\nYou added",p1_additem,"to your backpack.\n")

playeritems = []
addbackpack()
print (playeritems)
addbackpack()
print (playeritems)
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks, I also wrote the iterative approach for consideration.

Answer (score 1):

It *does* work (in that each new item gets added), but every call to `addbackpack` re-initializes `playeritems`, erasing all that had been there before.